# VB6 IDE cannot load MSCOMCTL.OCX after update KB 2687323

Tags: vb6

After windows update installed security update [KB2687323](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687323), my VB6 project fails to load. Displayed error message is "'[project_vbp_path]/MSCOMCTL.OCX' could not be loaded--Continue Loading Project?". Note that the path in the messeage is the vbp file folder path instead of the control's registered path.

Details:

1. MSCOMCTL.OCX is registered in the usual system32 folder.
2. The executable produced by exactly the same project, an hour before the update runs fine and loads the updated MSCOMCTL.OCX (I have checked it with Process Explorer).

The security update description states that MSCOMCTL.OCX has a new fixed version. So I checked the project properties for "Upgrade ActiveX Controls" checkbox. I tried it both ways; checked and unchecked to no avail. VB6 IDE refused to load the upgraded OCX.

Comment: My original statement in the question that "The 'Upgrade ActiveX Controls' checkbox has not effect" WAS WRONG. Thanks to Bob, I am now aware that I have somehow not managed to change this vbp property. It was stuck in "do not upgrade". This led to the problem. Details are in Bob Riemersma's comment and my answer below.

Comment: watch out: since the end of march 2013 a new cause for this problem has emerged, See auto's answer for details.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

After hours of effort, system restore, register, unregister cycles and a night's sleep I have managed to pinpoint the problem. It turns out that the project file contains the below line:

```
Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; MSCOMCTL.OCX
```

The version information "2.0" it seems was the reason of not loading. Changing it to "2.1" in notepad solved the problem:

```
Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.1#0; MSCOMCTL.OCX
```

So in a similar "OCX could not be loaded" situation one possible way of resolution is to start a new project. Put the control on one of the forms and check the vbp file with notepad to see what version it is expecting.

---

**OR A MUCH EASIER METHOD:**

(I have added this section after Bob's valuable comment below)

You can open your VBP project file in Notepad and find the nasty line that is preventing VB6 to upgrade the project automatically to 2.1 and remove it:

```
NoControlUpgrade=1
```

Comment: Funny.  I checked and I have this updated OCX too.  Then I dug up an old project that uses it and sure enough it has the 2.0 but it loads, compiles, and runs just fine.  Creating and saving a NEW project did show the 2.1 but it sure doesn't seem critical here.

Comment: It turns out that Bob Riemersma is also right. And after his comment I figured out why. Thanks Bob. The difference is a nasty line in my vbp stating "NoControlUpgrade=1" which controls the "Upgrade ActiveX Controls" checkbox in project properties. When you have the check ticked, this line does not appear in vbp and it silently upgrades the OCX to 2.1. When it is unchecked (i.e. it is 1) you cannot load the project. I am editing my answer in a minute to reflect this finding.

Comment: You are right, except that in my end it was the opposite, it was 2.1 and I've changed it to 2.0. Now it's working (on xp) :)

Comment: Thank you so much for me on Windows 7 it was 2.1 and I just change it t o 2.0

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I had to downgrade to 2.0 on Win 10.

Comment: Thank you so much, it finally worked on a very old project, in my case, the project was in 2.2, i had to downgrade it to 2.1.

Answer (score 42):

The problem has been resolved by running the following in elevated command prompt:

command :

```
cd C:\Windows\System32\
regtlib msdatsrc.tlb
```

or

```
cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
regtlib msdatsrc.tlb
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This one fixed it for me.  What in the world does msdatsrc.tlb have to do with MSCOMCTL?!?  Thank you so much!

Comment: There seems to be a new cause for the message "Object library not registered" since the end of march 2013. The code above solves it.

Comment: Wow work for me too.  I've Win7 but there is no **regtlib.exe**. But that made the trick `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regtlibv12.exe msdatsrc.tlb`

No more **Object library not registered** in VB6 :D.

and yes strange what have 
MSDATASRC => Microsoft Data Source Interfaces for ActiveX Data Binding to do with MSCOMCTL?

Well maybe it's because of the 'DTPicker'(to access certain Database/Recordsets ) from MSCOMCT2 that is somehow linked to MSCOMCTL.

Answer (score 13):

**The problem:**

Microsoft Office 2010 products (or later) install updates that break compatibility of MSCOMCTL.ocx and COMCTL32.ocx. Unfortunately this affects many other programs such  Visual Basic 6 SP6 and even Oracle Virtual Box v5. The actual problem is `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}\2.0` registry key. You can find detailed background information about this problem [here](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/controls/mscomctl/).

**Here is another working solution:**

The solution assumes you have not damaged your registry by deleting, replacing and re-registering MSCOMCTL.ocx and COMCTL32.ocx without unregistering the Office patch files.

Create a batch file called **fix.cmd** and place the following commands in it:

```
regsvr32 /s /u %windir%\SysWOW64\comctl32.ocx
regsvr32 /s /u %windir%\SysWOW64\mscomctl.ocx
del /y %windir%\SysWOW64\comctl32.ocx
del /y %windir%\SysWOW64\mscomctl.ocx
msiexec /passive /norestart /i KB2708437.msi
msiexec /passive /a KB2708437.msi
regtlib %windir%\SysWOW64\msdatsrc.tlb
```

Download from [Security update for Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 6: August 14, 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2708437) the msi file and rename it to **KB2708437.msi**.

Note: A direct link to the Service Pack 6 download is located [HERE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30505).

Run **fix.cmd** and the problem will be fixed!

What fix.cmd does is to properly unregister and then delete the current MSCOMCTL.ocx and COMCTL32.ocx files, and then apply the latest Visual Basic 6 SP6 rollup patch. In fact, the script enforces the patch to be installed and then re-installed by updating every file, regardless of version. Finally it registers msdatsrc.tlb type library.

Please let me know if this works for you.

======================================================================

**Advanced Solution:**

If however you have accidentally damaged your registry, you need to get as many versions of MSCOMCTL.ocx and COMCTL32.ocx you can find. Then you need to start from the newer version going back to the older and **register and unregister** the ocx files.

The latest version of MSCOMCTL.ocx is **6.1.98.39 (v2.1)** of May 2012 which is more likely the one installed on your system and causing all your problems.

The oldest (legacy) version is that shipped with Visual Basic 6 on 1998 **6.1.97.82 (v2.0)**, or the one shipped with an early service pack **6.1.97.86** on April 2005.

Example:

```
regsvr32 /s comctl32.6.0.98.34.ocx
regsvr32 /s /u comctl32.6.0.98.34.ocx

regsvr32 /s comctl32.6.0.81.6.ocx
regsvr32 /s /u comctl32.6.0.81.6.ocx 

regsvr32 /s comctl32.6.0.81.5.ocx
regsvr32 /s /u comctl32.6.0.81.5.ocx

regsvr32 /s mscomctl.6.1.98.39.(2.1).ocx
regsvr32 /s /u mscomctl.6.1.98.39.(2.1).ocx

regsvr32 /s mscomctl.6.1.98.34.ocx
regsvr32 /s /u mscomctl.6.1.98.34.ocx

regsvr32 /s mscomctl.6.1.97.86.ocx
regsvr32 /s /u mscomctl.6.1.97.86.ocx

regsvr32 /s mscomctl.6.1.97.82.(2.0).ocx
regsvr32 /s /u mscomctl.6.1.97.82.(2.0).ocx

regsvr32 /s /u %windir%\SysWOW64\comctl32.ocx
regsvr32 /s /u %windir%\SysWOW64\mscomctl.ocx

del /q %windir%\SysWOW64\comctl32.ocx
del /q %windir%\SysWOW64\mscomctl.ocx

msiexec /passive /norestart /i KB2708437.msi
msiexec /passive /a KB2708437.msi

regtlib %windir%\SysWOW64\msdatsrc.tlb
```

**WARNING:**

Do not search the internet for those files. To find different version of the OCX files download and extract official Microsoft Installer packages such as the following:

[2005 Apr - Microsoft KB896559](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896559)

[2008 Dec - Microsoft KB926857](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926857)

[2009 Apr - Microsoft KB957924](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957924)

[2012 May - Microsoft KB2708437](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2708437)

It is also recommended to run [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) version 4.0 or later to fix any other ActiveX related problems on your computer.

Comment: The best solution is using version 2.2 as mentioned in this answer.

Comment: I have the issue in my Virtual Machine (Windows XP). I run the command `Regsvr32 "C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX"` then fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

To Fix the Problem:

Make a Batch file with the following code:

```
@echo off
reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\typelib\{831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}\2.1"
if %errorlevel%==0 GOTO DELREGKEY
if %errorlevel%==1 GOTO REGISTEROCX

:DELREGKEY
reg delete hkcr\typelib\{831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}\2.0 /f

:REGISTEROCX
if exist %systemroot%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe goto 64 
%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32 /u mscomctl.ocx /s
%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32 mscomctl.ocx /s
exit

:64 
%systemroot%\sysWOW64\regsvr32 /u mscomctl.ocx /s
%systemroot%\sysWOW64\regsvr32 mscomctl.ocx /s
exit
```

Comment: Reference: http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2012/08/15/quot-unspecified-automation-error-quot-after-applying-ms12-060.aspx

Comment: Silvio these issues may be related but this IS NOT an answer to the VB6 IDE problem. I think you should remove it from here. As your reference artical states. The fix is for another problem.

Comment: Although I don't think this is the correct solution to this question it does serve a purpose. At my work our build server still operates on mscomctl 2.0 so it was convenient to roll back to 2.0 on our windows 7 machines.

Comment: Re-registering mscomctl.ocx alone does not solve the problem because the problem (in my case) is caused by a later version being improperly registered, and COM always picks the latest version when non is specified. Deleting the registration and *then* registering mscomctl.ocx fixed my problem. It fixed both a problem trying to create a new project referencing mscomctl and well as a problem trying to load an existing project that referenced version 2.0 specifically. Apparently the version there is ignored because the 2.1 registration still interfered.

Answer (score 5):

I use win7 and has same problem.
Today I solved this problem, through loading with many error with my project just give order to continue after that goto Project=> Component => Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6) then save the project (file use was c:\windows\syswow64\mscomctl.ocx)

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me is to install this VB6 patch.  I'm on Server2008 (32-bit).

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10019

It makes me sad that we're still talking about this in 2014... but here it is.  :)

---

From puetzk's comment: These are outdated: you want to be using [Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 6 Cumulative Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7030) ([kb957924](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957924)).

Comment: These are outdated: you want to be using [Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 6 Cumulative Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7030) ([kb957924](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957924))

Answer (score 2):

On some computers, I've found that the "2.0" version of `MSCOMCTL.OCX` has been added to the ActiveX KillBits list, and thus the control won't be allowed to load or run--even in design view. Updating to the "2.1" version will resolve this, and is the recommended solution.

In critical cases, where you *have to* run a program "now", or you don't have access to source code, or the control is used 400 times in a large modular project, you can use a "big hammer" method and update the registry to re-enable the control:

**
*WARNING*: Editing the Windows Registry in the wrong way can mess up your computer big time. If you're not sure what you're doing, please leave it alone, or get some schooling before you proceed.
**

The clear the KillBit:

> 1. Run Registry Editor (regedit.exe or regedt32.exe)
> 2. In the left-hand panel, navigate to key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ActiveX
>      Compatibility{BDD1F04B-858B-11D1-B16A-00C0F0283628}
> 3. In the right-hand panel, double-click on “Compatibility Flags”, change the value from Hex 0x400 (Decimal 1024) to 0, then click OK.
> 4. Launch the application that uses the "2.0" version of MSCOMCTL.OCX; it should run as designed.

The ActiveX KillBits list is intended to give Microsoft the means to disable controls that are deemed to be a security risk, and they've designed the mechanism such that the ActiveX KillBits list will be re-applied to the system at seemingly random times, in addition to when an Update is installed, so you'll need to plan for re-applying the registry change. Making a registry merge file works pretty well, but it's not something you want to do everytime the app runs, because it's not a quiet process (there are ways to do this quietly using Windows Scripting, but you'll have to learn that on your own). The KillBit is checked only when the control is requested by an application, so you're safe from resets once the application launches and loads the control.

Answer (score 2):

I do not find `NoControlUpgrade=1` on my vbp project. 
Instead, I develop on both xp and windows7 x64. When I moved the project from window 7 to xp, the error occurred.

From what I find out, these are different:

```
Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; MSCOMCTL.OCX

Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.1#0; MSCOMCTL.OCX
```

I just changed the `#2,1` back to `#2.0` on the vbp file and it can run immediately.
These kind of problems occurred before, so hope Microsoft explain and solve them accordingly.
Thanks.

Comment: This solution should work for you if you're stuck working on a box that only has the 2.0 version of COMCTL.OCX installed (e.g. virtual Win7 box with only VB6). The GUID remains the same for all versions of the control.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to check your registry

- **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib{831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}**

If it is 2.1 version, it will cause cannot load MSCOMCTL.OCX issue.

You may restore to 2.0 verion (**not only copy the file, you should unregiser 2.1 and register the restored file**)

Or

You may try latest 2.2 version

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3096896  (file date: 5-Nov-2015)
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50722

Some version information :

- 6.0.88.62 (2.0)
- 6.1.97.82 (2.0)
- 6.1.98.34 (2.1) <<< not work for me
- 6.1.98.46 (2.2)

Comment: What aobut Windows 10? When I load my project it shows that it cannot load the MSCAL.OCX - when I open the .vbp file with notepad it shows that it's #7.0#0; MSCAL.OCX

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with VBA Macros using MSCOMCTL.OCX.
Problem still unresolved with solutions like "reg/unreg mscomctl.ocx"
Used the Info above of Rumi.
Edited my *.dot file, search for #2.0#0, change it to #2.1#0
--> it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and tried many different solutions. They didn't work for me although I think this error occurs for a couple of different reasons. My solution is in my answer to this question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15785253/2240058

Its worth a try if nothing else is working for you.

Comment: Although your solution didn't work for me another answer to this question was the actual solution to my problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This problem mysteriously appeared for me today.  I hadn't done any Windows updates, so I don't know the cause.

This fixed it (in elevated command prompt):

regtlibv12.exe msdatsrc.tlb

Answer (score 0):

I recently put all my source on a windows 8 32 box. Had the issues loading `mscomctl.ocx` with existing projects.

I  created a new project and add the common control (all). save the project and reloaded it no problem.

when you compare the project headers new vs old the old one uses reference=*\blah blah. I found removing this a replacing it with the Object={blah} sorted out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this solution worked like a charm:
http://home.pacific.net.hk/~edx/bin/readmeocx.txt

Fix these two lines like that:

```
Object={F9043C88-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB}#1.2#0; COMDLG32.OCX
Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; MSCOMCTL.OCX
```

Search the files (.vbp and .frm) for lines like this:

```
Begin ComctlLib.ImageList ILTree
Begin ComctlLib.StatusBar StatusBar1 
Begin ComctlLib.Toolbar Toolbar1`
```

The lines may be like this:

```
Begin MSComctlLib.ImageList ILTree 
Begin MSComctlLib.StatusBar StatusBar1
Begin MSComctlLib.Toolbar Toolbar1`
```

Answer (score 0):

I continued to have problems after trying the things suggested here.  In the end, it turned out that I had the wrong version of `mscomctl.ocx` in my SysWOW64 folder.  I found the following versions kicking around:

```
Mar. 09, 2004  01:00 AM   1,081,616  mscomctl.ocx
Jun. 06, 2012  07:59 PM   1,070,152  mscomctl.ocx
Dec. 08, 2015  03:57 AM   1,070,232  MSCOMCTL.OCX
```

Getting the last one (1,070,232) solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar trouble, have a program running for last 10 years written in VB6, now client wanted to make some major modifications, and all my machines which are now windows 10; failed to open the project, it was always that nasty mscomctl.ocx error. I had  done lot of things but could not solve the problem. Then I thought the easy way around, I downloaded the latest mscomctl ([image: mscomctl.ocx]
Then opened a new project, added all the components like mscomctl, activx controls etc, saved it and opened this newly created project file in Notepad, then copied the exact details and replaced in the original project.... and bingo! The old project opened up normally without any fuss! I hope this experience will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case didn't work any solution above. Near to give up, removed any reference (using Arvo Bowen's fix.cmd file)  and tried pasting mscomctl.ocx (version 6.1.97.86) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98 folder. It worked finally after more than 4 or 5 hours fighting for a solution.