# Class MSComctlLib.[ListView|TextBox|ect] of control controlName was not a loaded control class

Tags: dll, vb6, compilation, compiler-errors

This error is from a machine compiling a vb6 dll which suddenly stopped working and used to work fine.

I've seen this on the net a lot the solutions that i could find and were relevant to me.
Including these ones which seemed promising from
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-140158.html
and one from
http://www.excelfox.com/forum/f2/missing-mscomctllib-15/

Both of these suggested re-registering the MSCOMCTL.OCX

But after following both of these I still had the problem.
After hours of searching and trying different things I realised that there were some updates which had been installed and waiting a reboot of the machine because of corporate policy.

## The Answer

I rebooted the machine and waited for the updates to finish installing.
After that the dll compiled without a problem.

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same issue after installing some Windows updates (including upgrading to IE10), and VS2012 Update 3, but the updates were fully installed, and MSCOMCTL.OCX was already COM-registered. On an other StackOverflow post I found about this issue, this finally resolved it for me:

Run a command prompt as Admin

Navigate to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 on 64-bit systems, or C:\Windows\system32 on 32-bit systems

Execute 'regtlib msdatsrc.tlb' (without quotes)

Credit goes to 'Auto':
[VB6 IDE cannot load MSCOMCTL.OCX after update KB 2687323](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982719/vb6-ide-cannot-load-mscomctl-ocx-after-update-kb-2687323)

I'm posting here since you're the first result when searching for this error.

Comment: It's been a few(!) years, things have moved around a bit, on my windows 7 machine I needed to use this: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regtlibv12.exe C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msdatsrc.tlb

Answer (score 2):

*This answer should work if the computer was compiling the dll/ocx at some point but isn't any more, but MAY also work if your computer never has compiled it either.*

So the simple answer to the question is to check if your machine has pending updates waiting for a reboot.

If so make sure that you reboot your machine.

If The problem is still occuring after a reboot then try re-registering MSCOMCTL.OCX which should be in your windows subdirectories; either **c:\windows\system32** or **c:\windows\SysWOW64**. *Note you use regsvr32 to register the ocx*.

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 (64bit) and I was having the same issue and I got thru as per below:

1. Go to the path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
2. Execute 'regtlibv12 msdatsrc.tlb' (without quotes)

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue with one of a production computer. It is a newly formatted PC with Windows XP as its OS. During this writing, we know that Windows XP does not offer updates anymore. What I did was, I installed VB6 since I have access to this software, afterwards, I installed [VB6 Service Pack 6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/details.aspx?id=5721) and the error was corrected. I have to install VB6 Enterprise because the installation of the service pack requires the data included in the installation of the said IDE.