# C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX could not be loaded

Tags: vb6

C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX could not be loaded

I Installed sp6 full service pack. also installed "windows common controls for SP6"
Then i went and registered
using Window7 64bit,
1.  Regsvr32 c:\windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX
2.  Regsvr32 c:\windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCT2.OCX

Now when i open my VB6 project, it still cannot load "MSCOMCTL.OCX"

Even after I go to Project --> Components --> under Controls tab --> MSCOMCTL.OCX

It gives me an error "C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX could not be loaded"

Link to my error Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0830b.png

Please help me.. this worked well on my system before. I dont know what went wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB6 IDE cannot load MSCOMCTL.OCX after update KB 2687323](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982719/vb6-ide-cannot-load-mscomctl-ocx-after-update-kb-2687323)