# Why do I get an Error: File mscomctl.OCX missing when running vb6 application in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, vb6

I have two PC with Windows 7 Professional x64. One PC can run my vb6 application successfully, but the other PC will occupy the following error message.

[image: Error Message]

I cannot figure out any reasons for the above situation. Is there any way I can try to identify the problem? Please help!

Comment: I have already followed the steps mentioned in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982719/vb6-ide-cannot-load-mscomctl-ocx-after-update-kb-2687323), but the problem still persists.

Comment: Really no one can help? I have already tried regtlib and checked "Upgrade ActiveX Controls" in my VB projects, the problem is still here. I have ensured the OCX is correctly registered.

Answer (score 6):

You can [see this MS statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708) that clarifies that VB6 *is* supported on Windows 7 (32-bit applications only though), and that the VB6 runtime is already included with the Operating System.

However, there are some files that you need to package and distribute with your application. These are:

[image: vb6]

You must make sure that you distributed and registered these files, which is usually done with some installer sofware like Installshield or NSIS, etc.

Comment: +1 Here's a good question on [how to create an installer for a Vb6 app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/how-to-create-a-simple-install-system-for-vb6-on-xp-vista)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added all the files mentioned into my installer. However, the error message still exists. I have already checked that the DLLs are registered successfully in sysWOW64 folder.